# Using subtype for parameter in method override

Tags: java, covariance

```
public abstract class SequenceItemHolder {

    public SequenceItemHolder(View itemView) {
    }

    public abstract void setData(SequenceRowElement.RowElement rowElement);


        public static class TesteItemHolder extends SequenceItemHolder {

        public TesteItemHolder(View itemView) {
        }

        @Override
        public void setData(SequenceRowElement.TestRowElement rowElement) {
        }
   }
}
```

Please can somebody explain me why do I get a compile error in the override?

Please how to fix it (without using an interface)?

---

NOTE: **TestRowElement extends RowElement**

Comment: what does the error message tells you?

Comment: One is a `RowElement`, the other a `TestRowElement`. Different type, so different signature, so not same method, so not overriding anything. --- And you also get error by having `{}` on a method declared `abstract`.

Comment: You are basicly overloading the method but not overriding it.

Comment: You should get rid of the first compile error first: body declaration at abstract method!

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that TestRowElement extends RowElement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error 1

```
public SequenceItemHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    }
```

Object doesn't have a constructor taking a View as parameter. Remove the super call.

Error 2

```
public abstract void setData(SequenceRowElement.RowElement rowElement) {}
```

abstract methods should not have a body. replace it with this:

```
public abstract void setData(SequenceRowElement.RowElement rowElement);
```

Error 3

Your overriden method should have the same parameter type as the abstract one.

Comment: No. It can't. a non-abstract method in an abstract class can, but an abstract method can't, you can't have a 'concrete abstract' method.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that TestRowElement extends RowElement

Comment: @LisaAnne doesn't change the fact you are overloading, not overriding. It needs to be the same type, not a related one.

Answer (score 2):

You are not overwriting the method ( = same method signature), you are overloading it (= same method name, different parameters)

```
public abstract void setData(SequenceRowElement.RowElement rowElement) {}

@Override
public void setData(SequenceRowElement.TestRowElement rowElement) {
}
```

Your first function (in `SequenceItemHolder`) takes a `SequenceRowElement.RowElement`as parameter, your second function takes a `SequenceRowElement.TestRowElement`.
Therefore, `@Override` is wrong.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that TestRowElement extends RowElement

Comment: @LisaAnne that doesn't matter. You can only call `setData(new TestRowElement())`, on `TesteItemHolder`, the superclass has no such method - so that cannot be an override.

Comment: This doesn't matter for the declaration. The signatures are different. if you replace `SequenceRowElement.TestRowElement` in your second function *declaration* with `SequenceRowElement.RowElement` you can still *use* the function with an `SequenceRowElement.TestRowElement`

Comment: It could actually matter, but only if it was the other way around - you could use a super-type in the override method and the subtype in the overriden method. You could also use subtype for an overriding method's return type. But not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

This is about what's formally called [covariance and contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Inheritance_in_object-oriented_languages).

Simply put, if you have a type hierarchy of `Animal` > `Mammal` > `Dog`, and the base method

```
Mammal foo(Mammal arg)
```

these are allowed as overrides:

- ```
  Mammal foo(Mammal arg)
  ```
- ```
  Mammal foo(Animal arg)
  ```
- ```
  Dog    foo(Mammal arg)
  ```
- ```
  Dog    foo(Animal arg)
  ```

That is, you can widen the parameter type (allowing more general input in the subclass' method) and narrow down the returned value (declaring that you will return a more specific type).

The reason is, the caller must be able to call the overriden method using the original signature - so the subclass method cannot have more specific parameters nor more general return value. In the example above, the caller must be able to call `foo` with parameter of type `Mammal` and the return value must be a `Mammal` - the parameter in subclass method therefore may be `Mammal` or `Animal` (both will accept an actual parameter of type `Mammal`), and may return a `Mammal` or a `Dog` (both can be stored in a variable of type `Mammal`).

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
    public abstract class SequenceItemHolder {

    public SequenceItemHolder(View itemView) {
    }

    public abstract void setData(SequenceRowElement.RowElement rowElement);

    public static class TesteItemHolder extends SequenceItemHolder {

        public TesteItemHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void setData(SequenceRowElement.RowElement rowElement) {          
        }
    }
}
```